# Prevent ASP.NET Website project from building certain directories by using Web.config?

Tags: asp.net, compilation, building, vs-web-site-project

While programming, the longest part is a build on my ASP.NET Website project is the "Building directory" process seen below. *(Note: I don't have the liberty to turn this into a Web Application with a .csproj build file. Wish I did.)*

The contents of the directories seen below are not changing although there might be some dependencies in the App_Code/ subfolders that do change.

**Is there any way for me to stop some directories from building using Web.config**, to shorten a compile of my dev copy? It's the only viable file I can think of to use without having an official build file.

```
------ Build started: Project: C:\...\cmsappmin-abcd\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Validating Web Site
Building directory '/cmsappmin-abcd/abcd/controls/docsearch/'.
Building directory '/cmsappmin-abcd/abcd/controls/'.
Building directory '/cmsappmin-abcd/abcd/controls/pipco/'.
Building directory '/cmsappmin-abcd/abcd/controls/reg1000/'.
Building directory '/cmsappmin-abcd/abcd/TemplateC/'.
Building directory '/cmsappmin-abcd/abcd/Template/'.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right click on the website project in solution explorer, and select *property pages*.

Under Build, change the following settings:

- Start action/Before running startup page - No Build
- Build solution action - uncheck "Build Web site as part of solution"

That will stop Visual Studio from building any pages when performing a build. When WebDev.Webserver starts, your pages will now be built as and when you access each directory.

Comment: I was looking for a more selective build of my website directories however after much consternation I believe your answer is the most sensible and flexible considering Website projects don't have an official build file.