# VS2017 Builds the whole Website on Start Debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I have a Website project (not Web Application), don't ask me why and whether I can turn it into a Web Application. Whenever I build solution, it won't build website, and when I hit play (Start Debugging), it always launched the project and built/compiled the pages ask I browsed the application. Well, until I installed VS Updates last night. How Starting Debugging builds the whole website, every directory and the process takes 20-25 minutes. I would love to disable that new feature that the VS2017 Update installed. How can I do that?

I am using VSc2017 v15.1 (26403.7)

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer at [a different question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2361153/1411014).

I disabled the Build of Website in the `Startup Action` of the Website in property pages.